# Use JS label syntax "$:" without "Cannot access <obj> before initialization" error

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper, svelte-3, svelte-component

I'm using this code in my Svelte app:

```
<script>
  import { query } from '@urql/svelte'

  import { MY_QUERY } from 'queries'

  $: myQuery = query({
    query: MY_QUERY,
    variables: { id }
  })
</script>

{#if !$myQuery}
  Loading...
{:else}
  Oh WOW! {$myQuery.data}
{/if}
```

Trying the same code in Sapper I get this error:

`Cannot access 'myQuery' before initialization`.

If I change the below line

- from this: `$: myQuery = query({`
- to this: `const myQuery = query({`

it works!

**Why?**

Comment: Warning to answerers: [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/) code is not pure JavaScript code, Svelte has a compilation step. That `$` thing you see is a [*reactive declaration*](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-declarations). (While yes, it is a JavaScript label, that's not its primary purpose above.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is Sapper code, and I don't see anything else obvious, I think you've run fool this [this bug](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3582). The error only happens on the server-side (SSR), doesn't it?

Then the workaround is to hint the compiler into declaring the variable in the right place:

```js
  let myQuery // <=== add this

  $: myQuery = query({
    query: MY_QUERY,
    variables: { id }
  })
```